# Nuget - how to package a reference C library

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I have a C# DLL that in turn calls a C library. How do I package these libraries in a NuGet package? 
For example, I have two DLLs MyCSharp.dll and MyC.dll 
How do I package both these DLLs so that when I add the NuGet package to a Windows Universal/UWP project, MyCSharp.dll is able to call MyC.dll successfully?

I tried adding copying the MyC.dll to the same folder as MyCSharp.dll during install time, but this doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by placing my MyC.dll & MyC.winmd libraries in the `build` folder of the NuGet package. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mim/archive/2013/09/02/packaging-a-windows-store-apps-component-with-nuget-part-2.aspx for very elaborate write up on packaging WinRT components with NuGet.